# Show that $T$ is diagonalizable iff $T_{W_i}$ is diagonalizable for all $i$.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, direct-sum, invariant-subspace

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

"Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$,
and let $W_1$, $W_2$,..., $W_k$ be $T-$invariant subspaces of $V$ such that $V =
W_1 \oplus W_2 \oplus···\oplus W_k$. Prove that $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $T_{W_i}$
is diagonalizable for all $i$."

I've already proven the first implication, but I'm stuck on the latter. I'm trying to use the fact that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ can be written as the product of the characteristic polynomials of the restrictions $T_{W_i}$ (since the subspaces are $T-$invariant and direct sum of $V$), but I don't know if I can prove the theorem following this path.

I can also minimal polynomial and Cayley-Hamilton if need be. Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier route.

Since $T_{W_i}$ is diagonalizable always, for each $i$ we have a basis of $W_i$, $\{v_{1,i},v_{2,i},\dots,v_{n_i,i}\}$ and an operator $S_i$ (on $W_i$) s.t. $(T(v_{j,i}))$ is always a scalar multiple of $v_{j,i}$.

Now, take the bases described for each of the $W_i$s and put them together. Then we get a basis for $\_\_\_\_\_$.

Then, the matrix representation of $\_\_\_\_\_$ with respect to $\_\_\_\_\_$ is obviously diagonal.

**FULL EXPLANATION:**

> When we combine the bases for the $W_i$s, we get a basis for $V$. Under this basis, the matrix representation of $T$ is then clearly diagonal.

note: if there is anything incorrect in my answer, feel free to edit or leave a comment

Comment: Why wouldn't you choose the basis so that $T(v_{j,i})$ is a multiple of $v_{j,i}$? Why introduce the operator $S_i$?

Comment: @TrevorGunn Now that I think about it, I'm not completely sure. I suppose a simplification in the answer would mean removing all mention of the $S_i$s and $S$?

Comment: When you have a matrix, it's defined in terms of a basis (like the standard basis for $F^n$). So to diagonalize a matrix, you have to introduce a matrix that changes the standard basis to your eigenbasis. But if you have an operator rather than a matrix it doesn't depend on any choice of basis. So you don't need to first pick one basis and then change that basis to an eigenbasis, you just pick the eigenbasis at the start.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Yes, but I was trying to preserve some part of the matrix notion of diagonalizability too. I guess this answer may be too restricted for that.

Comment: Also, the hard part of this statement is the converse. That is: if $T$ is diagonalizable and $W$ is $T$-invariant, then $T|_W$ is diagonalizable. I was thinking about if this can be done with just arguments about bases. Like if $\mathscr{B} = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is an eigenbasis for $V$, then is $\mathscr{B}_W = \mathscr{B} \cap W$ a basis for $W$? Or maybe this isn't true for a general eigenbasis and one instead needs to look at minimal polynomials to prove the converse. Unfortunately I don't have the time to think about this right now.